# Is there a name for a function that grabs a field from an object?

Tags: terminology

When passing around functions the term "predicate" is often used for a [short] function that returns a boolean. Is there a term for a function that selects a single field on an object?

For example let's say we build a custom sort function, but this sort is generic so it takes an argument for the user to specify which field to sort on. Such a function might look something like:

`sort(itemsToSort, functionThatGetsFieldToSortOn)`

The items might be an array of objects with a filename property.

`[{
   filename: 'foo'
}]`

If I were to sort based on filename with the function I might invoke a call like:

`sort(items, a => a.filename)`

This second argument...is there a special name for this type of function that selects a property?

I'm trying to figure out a good way to name this second argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is usually called a "getter".

In your sort() example, you actually need a "comparator", something that compares two items of a given type and tells you how they compare (less, equal, greater).

Comment: You can write a sort that takes a unary function and uses less than on the results, just as easily as one that takes a binary comparator

Comment: @Caleth: You can do that when your setter is returning a simple key with an obvious ordering that is native to the programming language in use.  Most languages do not provide obvious orderings on composite keys.  Using a comparator allows you to specify any ordering you want, be it obvious, non-obvious, or even bizarre, on any key you want, simple, composite, or computed on-the-fly as a function of one or more fields and/or one or more other things.

Comment: I didn't say *getter*, I said *unary function*. In the general case you can have "any ordering you want, be it obvious, non-obvious, or even bizarre, on any key you want, simple, composite, or computed on-the-fly" with that, too

Comment: `a => a.filename` is a unary free function. `Foo::filename` may be a getter, and may also be usable as a unary function (directly or as `foo => foo.filename()` or somesuch)

Comment: @Caleth: You are assuming in general the existence of a mapping from whatever simple, composite, or ad hoc on-the-fly key type you chose to (a subset of) the real numbers (i.e, something that the language knows how to compare), where that mapping preserves the desired ordering of the keys.  It is not clear that such a mapping will always exist.

Comment: You don't have to provide a mapping to reals. You can order (heterogenous!) composites lexicographically, element by element. The key extractor just has to compose whatever would be compared by the comparator, in the order that it compares. How else do you think a SQL `ORDER BY Col1, Function(Col2, Col3), Col4` is implemented by the query generator?

Comment: @Caleth: What if the ordering you want does not follow the default lexicographical ordering?

Answer (score 4):

A function that selects something from an object is often called a **selector**. Microsoft uses that term for the argument of the `Select`-function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx. Other examples are the name `keySelector` for the argument of the `GroupBy`-function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to indicate what the selector is for, give it a more specific name, like `keySelector`, `propertySelector` oder `fieldSelector`.